# ¿Cómo crear una matriz y completar la diagonal con valores de un vector?

Tags: r

Tengo un vector columna de 1 x 4000, y necesito crear una matriz simétrica, donde la diagonal contenga los elementos del vector columna y los demás espacios tenga cero algo como lo siguiente:

### Vector Columna

```
> vector<-matrix(c(1:5),ncol=1,nrow=5)
> vector
     [,1]
[1,]    1
[2,]    2
[3,]    3
[4,]    4
[5,]    5
```

#### matriz que quiero generar

```
 [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
a    1    0    0    0    0    0
b    0    2    0    0    0    0
c    0    0    3    0    0    0
```

No se si hay alguna forma de hacer?

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que lo que buscas es una matriz cuadrada dónde la diagonal sea el vector de entrada. Podrías hacer lo siguiente:

#### Usar un loop implícito mediante [`sapply()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html) y armar diagonal por filas

```
vector <- matrix(c(1:5),ncol=1,nrow=5)
sapply(1:nrow(vector), FUN=function(x) {v<-rep(0,nrow(vector));v[x]<-vector[x];v})

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    2    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    3    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    4    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    5
```

Es decir, con [`sapply()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html) vamos generando vectores de valores `0` por la longitud de nuestro `vector` para lo que sería cada fila (`v<-rep(0,nrow(vector))`) y solo modificamos el valor correspondiente a lo que sería la diagonal (`v[x]<-vector[x]`).

#### Usar [`diag()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/diag.html)

No hay que olvidar que podríamos usar [`diag()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/diag.html) para acceder directamente a la diagonal de cualquier matriz, por lo que si en primer lugar generamos una matriz de `0`, el completar la diagonal es trivial:

```
vector <- matrix(c(1:5),ncol=1,nrow=5)
matriz <- matrix(rep(0,nrow(vector)^2), nrow = nrow(vector))
diag(matriz) <- vector
```

#### Aclaración  con respecto a tu ejemplo:

En tu ejemplo, el resultado es una matriz rectangular, y solo tiene 3 de los valores originales, si eso es lo que buscas, puedes usar cualquiera de las soluciones anteriores pero con algunos cambios:

```
sapply(1:nrow(vector), FUN=function(x) {v<-rep(0,nrow(vector));v[x]<-vector[x];v})[1:3,]
```

O bien

```
matriz <- matrix(rep(0,nrow(vector)*3), ncol = nrow(vector))
diag(matriz) <- vector[1:3]
```